# Best way to code PerformanceCounters

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing a form which displays performance data and i have a few performance counters that displays some information about the processor and memory. As the first results is always "0" i am doing a sleep thread before assigning the next value. The problem by doing this is that it really makes the program sluggish.

Even moving the window is slow, and i bet its due to the thread sleep event which basicly is running every other second. I have set the timers to always enabled with an interval of 1 second, cause i want it to display information "realtime" sort of.

Here is my code so far:

```
    private PerformanceCounter pcProcess; //Process
    private PerformanceCounter pcMemory; //Memory

    private void tmrProcess_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        pcProcess = new PerformanceCounter(); //New Performance Counter Object
        pcProcess.CategoryName = "Processor"; //Specify Process Counter
        pcProcess.CounterName = "Interrupts/sec";
        pcProcess.InstanceName = "_Total";
        pcProcess.NextValue();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        cpInt.Text = pcProcess.NextValue().ToString(); //Display
        pcProcess.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        pcProcess.InstanceName = "_Total";
        pcProcess.NextValue();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        cpPower.Text = pcProcess.NextValue().ToString() + "%"; //Display
    }

    private void tmrMemory_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        pcMemory = new PerformanceCounter();

        pcMemory.CategoryName = "Memory";
        //This counter gives a general idea of how many times information being requested is not          where the application (and VMM) expects it to be
        pcMemory.CounterName = "Available MBytes";
        avlMem.Text = pcMemory.NextValue().ToString() + " Mb";
        pcMemory.CounterName = "Page Faults/sec";
        pcMemory.NextValue();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        pgFaults.Text = pcMemory.NextValue().ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Drop the idea of calling `Thread.Sleep`. It's almost **never** a good idea.
- Don't create a new instance of `PerformanceCounter()` on each timer tick, just call `perfmonCounter.NextValue()`.
- Call `NextValue()` once after the counter init so it'll returns something else than 0.0 on first timer tick. See `remarks` section on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue(v=vs.110).aspx :

> If the calculated value of a counter depends on two counter reads, the
>   first read operation returns 0.0. Resetting the performance counter
>   properties to specify a different counter is equivalent to creating a
>   new performance counter, and the first read operation using the new
>   properties returns 0.0. The recommended delay time between calls to
>   the NextValue method is one second, to allow the counter to perform
>   the next incremental read.

So basically:

```
private PerformanceCounter pcMemory;

private void InitPerfmon()
{
    this.pcMemory = new PerformanceCounter();
    this.pcMemory.CounterName = "Available MBytes";
    this.pcMemory.....
    ...
    this.pcMemory.NextValue();
}

private void tmrMemory_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.pgFaults.Text = this.pcMemory.NextValue().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Should i call performancecounter twice? So it will be this.pcMemory = new PerformanceCounter       this.pcProcess = new PerformanceCounter();

Comment: @user263029 Yes, you should have one instance for each counter you're monitoring